# Sum of standard deviations

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have two series:

$$A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$$
$$B = \{b_1,...,b_n\}$$

And I define the series C as:

$$C = \{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}$$

I am wondering if the standard deviation of $C$, $\sigma_C$, could be greater than the sum of the standard deviations of $A$ and $B$, that is, if it is possible that:

$$\sigma_C>\sigma_A+\sigma_B$$

I know that the relationship between the variances is:

$$\sigma_C^2=\frac12(\sigma_A^2+\sigma_B^2)+\left(\frac{\mu_A-\mu_B}2\right)^2$$

But I don't know how to extract conclusions from there. Does anybody know if this is possible? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If $A = \{1, 1, 1, 1\}$ and $B = \{2, 2, 2, 2\}$, then the variance of $C$ would be greater than the sum of the variances of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a trivial example, but say: $A = \{1,1,1,1,1\}$ and $B = \{5,5,5,5,5\}$. Then $\sigma_A = \sigma_B = 0$. Letting $C = A \cup B$, then $\sigma_C = 2$, so evidently:
$$
2= \sigma_C > \sigma_A + \sigma_B = 0 + 0.
$$